# Consecutive OpenSSL PKCS12 generation yields different private key content

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, private-key, pkcs#12

When using the same key and certificate file to create a PKCS12 (PKCS#12 / p12) file, I noticed that consecutive calls to `OpenSSL`'s `pkcs12` capability yields different `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` content each time (I'm also using the same import password and PEM passphrase). Is this supposed to happen?  I'm guessing it has something to do with a different IV (initialization vector) or salt related to a symmetric encryption of the private key, but I wanted to be sure.

I use the following command to create the cred1.p12 and cred2.p12 files:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certs/cert.pem -out cred1.p12 -name "My credentials" -inkey private/key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certs/cert.pem -out cred2.p12 -name "My credentials" -inkey private/key.pem
```

When I compare the resulting .p12 files (`diff cred1.p12 cred2.p12` results in binary differences) I use the following command to create the two `PKCS12` info text files, upon which I perform another `diff`.

```
 openssl pkcs12 -info -in cred1.p12 > a.txt
 openssl pkcs12 -info -in cred2.p12 > b.txt
 diff a.txt b.txt
```

And the only differences lie between the `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` tags where the private key content is held.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. OpenSSL uses DES-EDE3 by default for encrypting the private key in a PKCS12 file. Each time you encrypt it's generating a random [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector), which will change the encrypted payload. When you look at the -info output you'll see something like this:

```
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,558C30D119D6944F
```

The data after the comma is the hex encoded 8 byte salt.